# Google Speech to text API just returns false

Tags: php, google-cloud-speech

I have tried everything I know to get the Google Speech to text API to return anything but false but to no avail.  I made sure my flac file was a single channel file (ffmpeg -i test.flac -ac 1 test1.flac)  - still nothing.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
// Your API Key goes here.
$apiKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$audioFile = realpath(__DIR__ . '/test.flac');
$url="https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?key={$apiKey}";
$audioFileResource = fopen($audioFile, 'r');
$base64Audio = base64_encode(stream_get_contents($audioFileResource));
$settings=array(
    'config'=> array(
        'encoding'=>'FLAC',
        'sampleRateHertz'=>44100,
        'maxAlternatives'   => 3,
        'languageCode'      => 'en-US'
    ),
    'audio'=>array(
        'content'=>$base64Audio
    )
);
$json=json_encode($settings);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,           1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $json ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Content-Type: application/json')); 

$result=curl_exec ($ch);
var_dump($result);
exit;
```

UPDATE: I have updated the code so that this now works.  I had two things wrong. First it was "sampleRateHertz" instead of "sampleRate" in the config settings. Secondly, I had to disable the SSL verification on the peer.  This now works.

Returns the following:

```
    D:\>php GoogleSpeechToText_example.php
string(320) "{
  "results": [
    {
      "alternatives": [
        {
          "transcript": "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog",
          "confidence": 0.9850106
        },
        {
          "transcript": "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog",
          "confidence": 0.90610087
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just by luck I figured out the problem.  I had to add the following line of code:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```